# owl carousel адаптивность

Tags: html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Работаю с данным плагином впервые возникла проблема. На полном экране все выглядит нормально, но примерно с пикселей 700 начинается проблема с адаптивом (появлятся горизонтальный скролл и белая полоса сбоку), чем дальше, тем она больше. Вот так это выглядит на 5ке. Проблема,похоже,в том, что сбоку начинает лезть граница следующего item, как это можно исправить?) 
[image: скролл]

```
<div class="slider" id="catalog">
    <h2>Каталог продукции</h2>
    <hr>
  <div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="sl slide1"> <img src="img/slide1.png"> </div>
  <div class="sl slide2"> <img src="img/slide2.png"> </div>
  <div class="sl slide3"> <img src="img/slide3.png"> </div>
  <div class="sl slide4"> <img src="img/slide4.png"> </div>
    <div class="sl slide5"> <img src="img/slide5.png"> </div>
    <div class="sl slide6"> <img src="img/slide6.png"> </div>
    <div class="sl slide7"> <img src="img/slide7.png"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//

```
.slider{
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;

}

.slider h2{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 20px;
}

hr{
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
}

.slider .owl-carousel .owl-item img{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto ;
}

.slider .owl-carousel .owl-item{  
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto ;

}


.slider .owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 45%;
}
.slider .owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next{

  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 5%;

}
.owl-carousel .fa {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 28px;
    color: grey;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

//JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    nav:true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    responsiveClass:true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>']
  })

});
```

Comment: Судя по скрину, с каруселью у вас все нормально. Проверьте по всей странице элементы, у которых ширина равна ~700 - это самое первое, на что стоит обращать внимание при возникновении горизонатльного скролла и таких пустых просветов

Comment: @Cheg просмотрел элементы, кажется все в порядке, только owl-stage занимает это место